# Why is my XSL unable to be trasnformed into an XML doc and how do I get it to validate?

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, dtd

I have been working on my first XSL file all weekend and Monday but not only is something wrong with it that is not allowing me to transform it into an XML document based on the DTD, but it also has errors that I cannot seem to figure out. I managed to fix some obvious issues, but all the assignment is asking me to do is:

Add the "customers" element to the root template, apply the order template and add an id attribute node, using the custid as the value... Then create the order element with the order id attribute taking from the source, then adding other elements and attributes with values taken from the source as well. Maybe I am having so many issues because all of the examples I read used HTML tags inside the XSL doc, but this one has to be XML format.

Here is my code and the source:

```js
<!ELEMENT customers (customer)*>

<!ELEMENT customer (order)>
<!ATTLIST customer id CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT order (qty, date, amount)>
<!ATTLIST order orderid CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT qty (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT date (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT amount (#PCDATA)>



​
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml"
  doctype-system="customers.dtd"
  encoding="ISO-8859-1"
  indent="yes" />
  
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:comment>
 Author: Paulina Crawford
 Date: 10/10/2015
 </xsl:comment>
 
<xsl:element name="customers">
  <xsl:apply-templates
   select="orders/order">
      <xsl:sort select="custid" />
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:apply-templates select="order">
<xsl:element name="customer">
 <xsl:attribute name="id">
   <xsl:value-of select="@custid" />
 <xsl:element name="order">
 <xsl:attribute name="orderid">
   <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
   <xsl:element name="qty">
   <xsl:value-of select="@qty" />
   <xsl:element name="date">
   <xsl:value-of select="date" />
   <xsl:element name="amount">
   <xsl:value-of select="amount" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>​
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="clist.xsl" ?>

<orders>
   <order id="OR3124" qty="1" custid="CUST204">
      <date>5/1/2017</date>
      <amount>$108.24</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3125" qty="2" custid="CUST117">
      <date>5/1/2017</date>
      <amount>$78.21</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3126" qty="1" custid="CUST311">
      <date>5/1/2017</date>
      <amount>$45.93</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3127" qty="4" custid="CUST091">
      <date>5/2/2017</date>
      <amount>$68.21</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3128" qty="1" custid="CUST137">
      <date>5/2/2017</date>
      <amount>$117.24</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3129" qty="1" custid="CUST128">
      <date>5/3/2017</date>
      <amount>$75.68</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3130" qty="2" custid="CUST083">
      <date>5/3/2017</date>
      <amount>$58.93</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3131" qty="1" custid="CUST304">
      <date>5/3/2017</date>
      <amount>$112.25</amount>
   </order>
</orders>​
```

The error I am getting keeps saying that I must "terminate the  or element tag" because it is a duplicate or something... If anyone can please help, it would be much appreciated...Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT has to be well-formed XML, and that mean for every opening tag you must have a closing tag, but you are missing alot. For example when you create a `qty` element, you do this...

```
  <xsl:element name="qty">
      <xsl:value-of select="@qty" />
```

But there is no closing `</xsl:element>` tag visible. If you try indenting your XSLT, with closed tags lined up with opening tags, then it would be more obvious.

Your XSLT should probably look like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-system="customers.dtd" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:comment>
    Author: Paulina Crawford
    Date: 10/10/2015
    </xsl:comment>

    <xsl:element name="customers">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="orders/order">
            <xsl:sort select="custid" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="order">
    <xsl:element name="customer">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@custid" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="order">
            <xsl:attribute name="orderid">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:element name="qty">
                <xsl:value-of select="@qty" />
           </xsl:element>

            <xsl:element name="date">
                <xsl:value-of select="date" />
           </xsl:element>

            <xsl:element name="amount">
                  <xsl:value-of select="amount" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that you don't really need `xsl:element` here to create element names. Just write out the element you wish to output directly. Try this too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-system="customers.dtd" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:comment>
    Author: Paulina Crawford
    Date: 10/10/2015
    </xsl:comment>

    <customers>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="orders/order">
            <xsl:sort select="custid" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </customers>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="order">
    <customer id="{@custid}">
        <order orderid="{@id}">
            <qty>
                <xsl:value-of select="@qty" />
            </qty>
            <date>
                <xsl:value-of select="date" />
            </date>
            <amount>
                <xsl:value-of select="amount" />
            </amount>
        </order>
    </customer>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) in creating some of the attributes. The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes more sense now!